# Building fast webservices

Tags: java, php, performance, web-services, web

I want to provide components built in different programing languages (Java, C#, php, and perl) to many php websites without providing the source code of these component i.e. I want to provide the services not the components.
I  am thinking of building web services for each of these components and provide these web services to the websites.

**My question is:**

Do you think this will affect the performance of website in a noticeable way (in most cases there would be only one web services' call, rarely pages contain 2-3 calls).
And do you recommend any practice in building these web services to minimize the negative effects, I mean if you recommend one of the last mentioned languages (Java, C#, php, and perl) I can re-program all components in this language (Note: most of components are in Java).

Comment: Not so much performance, but rather pain in the ass to maintain is what I'm thinking.

Comment: do you have a specific example of what service you are providing?

Comment: Many services related to text processing

Comment: @PeeHaa don't see any pain. Many frameworks support RESTful serveices nova days. So you may look at view popular. If you have any knowledge in PHP, then there is no trouble at all. Even more due to low amount of requests I think you'll be fine.

Comment: That's pretty much how Amazon Web Services work (for example) ... services over the interwebs. Many companies build enterprise apps deeply coupled into AWS, Google APIs, Zillow ... et al.This is a pretty normal paradigm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means uncommon today. Perversely, it may both increase and decrease perceived performance at the same time if built correctly. Instead of making all the rest calls on the back end before rendering the page, send back a page that makes AJAX calls to the web services. Your initial load will be shorter because not all of the content will load at first, and the overall load before all the content appears will take longer, but people are pretty used to that.

Comment: sorry I don't know if I got the idea correctly when you say 'This is by no means uncommon today', which is the uncommon habit?

Comment: Building a website backed by some type of web service. Look at any of Google's pages. Look at Facebook. Stackoverflow, Netflix... Pick a website and watch the network traffic in Firebug. I'd bet the balance of them have some web service call or other in them.

Answer (score 0):

The most slower will be: the network communication. calling web-services
The seconds most slower will be the database query, if you do on your components.

You can have as text/xml that communication, Marshalling/Unmarshalling in Java for xml <-> object. A bit faster the JSON, because less tags. The fastest is the binary protocol.Not really affect your site performance the protocol changing, unless you have a huge traffic